# How to post demo requests into elasticsearch in kubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

Making first steps in elasticsearch and reading article 
https://www.elastic.co/blog/a-practical-introduction-to-elasticsearch
I tried to POST sample data in the console of my kubuntu 18, but pasting data 
and pushing enter key my data are not posted:

[image]

Why? How can I post these data ?
Can you advice some good client tool to work with elasticsearch data in my kubuntu 18 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked into your image and you are simply copying the payload to index a document in your `person` index, while as you are creating it using the command line and not using rest-client like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) which can be very handy to make Elastisearch API calls as all of its API are in JSON format.

But still, if you want to use the command line **then you need to properly use the curl which you already used to verify Elasticsearch** in running(as shown in your image.)

In every Elasticsearch example, Elasticsearch provides a way to directly copy the curl command as shown in below image of [index document example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#_create_document_ids_automatically):

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! But does Practical Introduction link in my topic has similar "Copy as cURL" url ?

Comment: @PetroGromovo, glad to hear back, nope what you are following is the blog there you wont find the `copy as curl` option, it will be available only when you follow the example given on elastic API pages like the one I gave in my answer :)